# Why isn't pytesseract recognizing this image?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, pytesser

It can read other images fine, it just can not read this one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBmrN.png)

```
import numpy as np
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract


img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Coding\PNGs\tugteam project\tugteam2.png')

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, img) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)


img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 400))



cv2.imshow('asd',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

I tried resizing the image, converting it to grayscale b/w w/b nothing will work.

Comment: Try resizing before thresholding.  After a resize, you get new colors again due to the bilinear interpolation.

Comment: if the argument to `image_to_string` looks okay, it's unlikely to be an OpenCV issue. I believe that to be the case and have removed the OpenCV tag. this looks like a pure tesseract issue.

Comment: Decrease size e.g. to 73 x 31